# Grabbing style.display property via JS only works when set inline?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to grab the DISPLAY property of a div on a page. I can only seem to grab it if it was set via an inline style attribute.

If my JS is this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display);
```

It will alert 'block' with this HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: block;"></div>
```

However, if I set it via an external style sheet:

```
#myID {display: block}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

then my alert is an empty string.

Why is this?

Comment: Are you running your javascript before loading your HTML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a "feature" of CSS. To actually get the style, you need to use *[window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle)* (most browsers) or *element.currentStyle* (Internet Explorer).

A fix to implement *window.getComputedStyle* IE can be found at: http://snipplr.com/view/13523/getcomputedstyle-for-ie/. Additionally, see this page for more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html#link7 (there is a script near the bottom for a cross-browser getComputedStyle alternative).

This should work in all browsers (based on function from QuirksMode link above):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if (elem.currentStyle) {
    var displayStyle = elem.currentStyle.display;
} else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display");
}
alert(displayStyle);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for that explanation! I'm surprised I haven't ran into this particular issue up to this point.