# javascript function executing on second click

Tags: javascript, css, variables, width, getelementbyid

I have a need to collapse/expand the width of a div (rather that hide/show), and for some reason this code that I wrote only seems to start working with the second click. If it put an alert in to check the variable it seems that the variable is not picking up the style initially. Any thoughts? Here is a js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JKxHw/4/

Here is my css, html, and script

```
#left_nav {width:200px; border: 1px solid red; height: 300px;}

<div id="left_nav_collapser">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:hideNav();return false;">collapse width of left nav</a>
</div>

<div id="left_nav">
<div id="left_nav_navlinks">
<ul><li>Apples<ul><li>Macintosh</li><li>Styrofoam</li></ul>
</li><li>Oranges</li><li>Bananas</li></ul>
</div>
   </div>
<script>
function hideNav(){

var myLayer = document.getElementById('left_nav').style.width;
//alert(myLayer);
if(myLayer=="200px"){
    document.getElementById('left_nav').style.width="0px";
    document.getElementById('left_nav_navlinks').style.display="none";
    } else {
    document.getElementById('left_nav').style.width="200px";
    document.getElementById('left_nav_navlinks').style.display="block";
};

}
</script>
```

More info: as much as I would love to I can not use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.style` only gets information from the style attribute rather than computed styles.  You could use `window.getComputedStyle` instead, but it seems inflexible to me.  Instead you should just have a variable that keeps track of the visibility state that the element is in.

You can even use `.dataset` (assuming you don't need to support IE) on the element itself, although any variable would do.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKxHw/6/

Comment: Thanks. I need to support all browsers. I found a fix based on your info. This is closer to what I used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083872/grabbing-style-display-property-via-js-only-works-when-set-inline