# javascript: how can i get DIV width/height instantly even if changed on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to get a div width and height through Java-script, and i got width and height when page load, but i hover div so it is not showing me width/height update size. i need when div on hover increase width or height also move/increase and show in div size increasing. i also need when i make css animation with/height 50% to 100% so also show me the width/height animation in pixels.

here is Example what i need. when div width/height increase so also increase values in top black area [Video Link](https://share.nexshot.io/vZeowwqe)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#w-count").html($('.animating-width').width());
  $("#h-count").html($('.animating-width').height());
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #292a2b;
  color: #FFF;
}

.animating-width {
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
  background: #e78629;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  -moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}
.animating-width:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
hr{
  border-color:#e78700;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animating-width">on Hover width 100%<hr> <span id="w-count"></span>x<span id="h-count"></span></div>
```

Comment: @hasan u can try this . http://api.jquery.com/height/
here u will get a complete example

Comment: @misorude i need the value in `id="w-count"` and `id="h-count"`

Comment: Well then you need an interval or something to constanlty check the current values and update your output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822889/get-css-value-mid-transition-with-native-javascript

Comment: Now brother, see this [Link](https://share.nexshot.io/vZeowwqe)  this is example i need this when hover div so show me what width/height is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create interval using `setInterval()` and get width of element in interval.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#w-count").html(
    Math.round($('.animating-width').width())
  );
  $("#h-count").html(
     Math.round($('.animating-width').height())
  );
}, 10);
```

```js
$("#w-count").html($('.animating-width').width());
$("#h-count").html($('.animating-width').height());
setInterval(function(){
  $("#w-count").html(
    Math.round($('.animating-width').width())
  );
  $("#h-count").html(
     Math.round($('.animating-width').height())
  );
}, 10);
```

```css
html {
  background: #292a2b;
  color: #FFF;
}
.animating-width {
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
  background: #e78629;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  -moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}
.animating-width:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
hr{
  border-color:#e78700;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animating-width">on Hover width 100%<hr> <span id="w-count"></span>x<span id="h-count"></span></div>
```

Also you can use `.animate()` instead of CSS transition.

```js
$("#w-count").html($('.animating-width').width());
// store first width of element
var width = $(".animating-width").width();
// mouseover & mouseout event
$(".animating-width").mouseover(function(){
  anim('100%');
}).mouseout(function(){
  anim(width);
});
// function of animation
function anim(width){
  $(".animating-width").stop().animate({
    width: width
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    step: function(){
      $("#w-count").html($(this).width());
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html {
  background: #292a2b;
  color: #FFF;
}
.animating-width {
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
  background: #e78629;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
}
.animating-width:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
hr{
  border-color:#e78700;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animating-width">on Hover width 100%<hr> <span id="w-count"></span>x<span id="h-count"></span></div>
```

Comment: if i need width and height both increase so?

Comment: @hassan You can add new parameter to function for height of element

Comment: it's showing value in points and no need to add width or height in javascript just put width or height in css.

Comment: see bottom answer of ssamuel, that code is working but just values shows in point. i need to remove value after point.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {$("#w-count").html($('.animating-idth').width());$("#h-count").html($('.animating-width').height());});$(".animating-width").hover(function(){setInterval(function(){$("#w-count").html($('.animating-width').width());$("#h-count").html($('.animating-width').height());},50);});`

how can i add `Math.round()` in this code please?

Comment: because you added height in javascript an i don't need width/height in javascript

Comment: @hassan This is my first solution that used width/height in CSS

Answer (score 3):

Using setInterval will render the height and width of the div at specific intervals on hover.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#w-count").html($('.animating-width').width());
  $("#h-count").html($('.animating-width').height());
});

$(".animating-width").hover(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      $("#w-count").html( Math.trunc($('.animating-width').width()));
      $("#h-count").html( Math.trunc($('.animating-width').height()));
   }, 100);
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #292a2b;
  color: #FFF;
}

.animating-width {
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
  background: #e78629;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  -moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}
.animating-width:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
hr{
  border-color:#e78700;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animating-width">on Hover width 100%<hr> <span id="w-count"></span>x<span id="h-count"></span></div>
```

Comment: brother, in this code also showing the values in points like `109.365` so if i need only values before the point so what can we do?

Comment: and i also added top and bottom padding so original height is `120` so it's showing `100`

Comment: you can use Math.trunc() function if you want to exclude the fractional part

Comment: i am at learning point so if you can help me to make it so i am so thankful please thanks.

Comment: I have updated the code to exclude the point values...Please check if it works

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't bind it to a `.hover()` or `.mouseover()` method. I'd build it externally and encapsulated to be more flexible.

```
const [d,resize,opt,ani] = [
    $('div'),
    ()=> d.html(Math.ceil(d.width())+'px'),
    {duration:1e3, step:()=> resize()},
    n=> ()=> d.stop().animate({width:n+'%'}, opt)
]
d.hover(ani(100),ani(50))
```

```js
const [d,resize,opt,ani] = [
 $('div'),
 ()=> d.html(Math.ceil(d.width())+'px'),
 {duration:1e3, step:()=> resize()},
 n=> ()=> d.stop().animate({width:n+'%'}, opt)
]
d.hover(ani(100),ani(50))
resize()
```

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/fbLau8p0/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var targetElement = document.getElementById('target');
var height = 0;
var width = 0;
var updatePosition = function(){
   height = targetElement.offsetHeight;
   width = targetElement.offsetWidth;
};
updatePosition();
targetElement.addEventListener("mouseover", updatePosition);
window.addEventListener("resize", updatePosition);
window.addEventListener("scroll", updatePosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use transition end event

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        DetectTransitionEnding = 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend';


      calcSize = function() {
          $("#w-count").html($('.animating-width').width());
          $("#h-count").html($('.animating-width').height());
      }

      calcSize(); // first writting

      myBox = $(".animating-width");


      myBox.hover(function () { 
          myBox.addClass('changeSize');
          myBox.one(DetectTransitionEnding, calcSize);
      });

      myBox.mouseout(function () { 
          myBox.removeClass('changeSize');
          myBox.one(DetectTransitionEnding, calcSize);
      });

    });
```

```css
    html {
      background: #292a2b;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    .animating-width {
      padding: 10px 0;
      text-align: center;
      background: #e78629;
      color: white;
      height: 100px;
      width: 50%;
      -moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
      transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .animating-width.changeSize {
      width: 100%;
    }

    hr {
      border-color: #e78700;
      border-bottom: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animating-width">on Hover width 100%
        <hr />
        <span id="w-count"></span>
        x
        <span id="h-count"></span>
    </div>
```